# Hiding a column in conjunction with hiding a tab with VBA?

Tags: excel, tabs, hide, vba

On Sheet 1, I have an array of individual columns that draw references from the respective tabs. So on Column 32, it will be referencing from Sheet 32. However, I don't need to see all the sheets and columns all the time. I need some help with how, if when I hide/unhide a tab, it will also hide/unhide the column?

Comment: I assume you'd need to handle an event fired when the sheet is hidden. However, I don't see an event associated with that. I can't think of another way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are Hiding and Unhiding the sheets namually, they Deactivate and activate as you hide/unhide.

Therefore use the Deactivate and Activate events to process the action

Something like (place code in the `Thisworkbook` module)

```
' Hide column when sheet is deactivated
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh.CodeName <> "Sheet1" Then
        If Sh.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then
            Sheet1.Columns(Sh.Index).Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub

' Show column when sheet is activated
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh.CodeName <> "Sheet1" Then
        If Sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
            Sheet1.Columns(Sh.Index).Hidden = False
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Note: I have assumed Sheet index and Column numbers are aligned.  Adjust as required to suit your actual workbook layout.